# Facebook API: Poll available permissions from Page Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Given a **Page Access Token**, how do I poll Facebook's API to determine whether my app can still post on the Page's timeline?  If I was working within the User's context, this would be easy.  I would use the **User Access Token** and call this endpoint:

```
/me/permissions?access_token={user_access_token}

{
  "data":[{
    "installed":1,
    "email":1,
    "publish_stream":1, // Yay! I can still publish to user's Timeline
    "bookmarked":1
  }]
}
```

However, the /me/permissions endpoint is not allowed with the **Page Access Token**:

```
/me/permissions?access_token={page_access_token}
{
  "error":{
    "message":"(#3) App must be on whitelist",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":3
  }
}
```

If I had the User's access token, then I can check for both **publish_stream** and **manage_pages** and if the user has granted both of those permissions, then my App can publish to any Page that the user is an administrator of.  But unfortunately in my scenario, I don't have the **User Access Token**.  I only have the **Page Access Token** which is stored for offline use.

Any idea how I can use the Page Access Token to determine if my App can still publish to the Page's Timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `debug tool` to check what information is associated with it.

Quoted from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/)

> To use the API, you can issue an HTTP GET request to graph.facebook.com/debug_token with two parameters:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> input_token: the Access Token to debug
> access_token: your App Access Token or a valid User Access Token from a developer of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to view page access token permissions using just the page access token.

Visiting /debug_token/, or using the Facebook Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) on the page access token will simply return the permissions of the user token that issued it (tested as of 5/7/14).

The only way to check page token permissions is by polling /me/accounts/ (which requires as user token from a page admin) and looking at the 'perms' field. Or by just testing requests.

Verifying 'manage_pages' and 'stream_publish' returned from /debug_token/ on a page token is an insufficient check, as the user's page admin level may restrict their activities.

Comment: Have a look at @Anvesh Saxana's answer.  It works well.

Comment: @JohnnyO Thanks, but I did try this, and when I used it with a page token, I got back the permissions of the user token that issued the page token. Could you paste an example of the output you're getting from the request when used with a page token?

Comment: here's an example response.  I simplified the headers a bit and changed some of the IDs:  

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 293

{"data":{"app_id":123456789,"is_valid":true,"profile_id":123456789,"application":"Sample App","user_id":1111111,"issued_at":1368654391,"expires_at":0,"scopes":["public_profile","basic_info","email","share_item","publish_stream","manage_pages","publish_actions","user_friends"]}}

Comment: part of the confusion may be that what you need to look at the user's permission to determine if you're granted page permissions.  For example, if the user has granted you manage_pages and publish_stream, then you can post on the Page's behalf using the page access token.